# Replace strings with objects in nested arrays

Tags: javascript

I have a large JS object which I feed to a factory. The original object contains strings in an array which are a parameter for the factory.

I would like to shorten the code to as short as possible and hopefully be functional.

What I have so far:

```js
const myConfigObject = {
  label: 'something',
  children: [
    {
      id: 'one',
      style: 'some style',
      children: ['key1', 'key2']
    },
    {
      id: 'two',
      style: 'some other style',
      children: ['key3', 'key4']
    },
  ]
}

function DummyFactory (key) {
  return {
    id: key,
    data: 'generated stuff'
  };
}

// How to optimize this call?
myConfigObject.children.forEach(child => {
  child.children = child.children.map(subChild => DummyFactory(subChild))
});

console.log(myConfigObject);
```

Comment: What's your problem here?

Comment: What do you mean by "optimize"? If you must to visit each string, you can't reduce iterations number.. May be use webworkers to parallelize the work?

Comment: IMHO this is already pretty well optimized; if you're still looking for pointers, this should go on codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: I was hoping to reduce it to a one liner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's not much to do here, but I would go for

```
function DummyFactory(key) {
  return {
    id: key,
    data: 'generated stuff'
  };
}
const myConfigObject = {
  label: 'something',
  children: [
    {
      id: 'one',
      style: 'some style',
      children: ['key1', 'key2'].map(DummyFactory)
    },
    {
      id: 'two',
      style: 'some other style',
      children: ['key3', 'key4'].map(DummyFactory)
    },
  ]
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Trying to shortening:

```
myConfigObject.children.forEach(
 child => child.children = child.children.map(DummyFactory));
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve expected use below option of even avoiding DummyFactory

```
myConfigObject.children.forEach(child => {
  child.children = child.children.map(subChild=> {
  return {
    "id":subChild,
    "data": 'generated stuff'
    }   
  })
});
```

code sample - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/VxWJYd?editors=1010

```js
const myConfigObject = {
  label: 'something',
  children: [
    {
      id: 'one',
      style: 'some style',
      children: ['key1', 'key2']
    },
    {
      id: 'two',
      style: 'some other style',
      children: ['key3', 'key4']
    },
  ]
}


myConfigObject.children.forEach(child => {
  child.children = child.children.map(subChild=> {
  return {
    "id":subChild,
    "data": 'generated stuff'
    }   
  })
});

console.log(myConfigObject);
```